# How to handle appcache quota exceeded error?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-appcache, application-cache

In Chrome, I have an app using the applicationCache and halfway through an update, I get an error that says "failed to commit new cache to storage would exceed quota". This causes the application to break and never update again. Any ideas how to handle this error case?

Comment: * Try to free up the space at the disk where Chrome resides


or/and


* Delete the contents of indexed DB storage, at Windows 7 the path is 

C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Answer (score 0):

- Try to free up the space at the disk where Chrome resides

or/and

- Delete the contents of local indexed DB storage

At Windows 7 the path for this data is

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB

Answer (score 0):

Try this link and delete existing cache data. chrome://appcache-internals/